# Errors in plugins make a 500 server error with no error message on screen or in log

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have an issue with errors generated in WordPress plugins that is making development difficult for me.

If I trigger an error in a normal PHP file like so:

```
trigger_error("an error occurred", E_USER_ERROR);
```

It works fine and I will get the error displayed on the page.  However, if I try the same in the code of a plugin the server generates a 500 error in browser and does not display the error.

In addition, it also does not log any error in the PHP-FPM or Nginx log file when occuring from plugin code.  This is making development extremely difficult as when I get an error I have no information to go on.

As this is working fine in standalone PHP I am assuming it must be WordPress related.

I have debugging enabled in wordpress.  My stack is as follows:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- PHP 7.0.4
- Nginx 1.10.0
- MariaDB 10.0.24

The file ownership is `user:www-data`. Directories are 775 and files are 664

Errors are enabled in the PHP conf files and I can see errors fine with standalone PHP pages, it is just happening on the server in context of errors happening in the WordPress plugins PHP pages.

This is very frustrating as I cannot see why this is happening.  Does anyone have any insight that could help me figure this out?

**EDIT**

To be more clear here is what I have in wp-config to enable debugging:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Other debugging values are defaulted to true so this should be all I need.

Curiously I have just noticed that error_log() does not do anything inside a WordPress file while trigger_error() will cause the 500 error.

This feels like some sort of permission based error but I am not sure what.  I really need some help with this as development in this circumstance is practically impossible without any error text.

Comment: file permission errors usually return a 403 error, a 500 error usually means the server script is failing, but if it is not giving any diagnosis in error logs perhaps you need to use old fashioned break point analysis to see where it is breaking down first.  Looking more closely at the bit of code that is breaking is easier than searching for needles in haystacks.

Comment: The error isn't a file permission error (I am throwing it myself) but the fact that it isn't logging the error or displaying it makes me think that it is a permission error with php/nginx in some way.  It is just a hunch, If I knew what was causing it then I would fix it but I am here trying to find help to do so.  I really need to be able to get error messages, debugging applications line by line and inspecting values just to get a hint what the error might be does not seem like a suitable solution to me.  I just need to be able to get the error messages rather than using a workaround.

Comment: general errors are a catch all for something language writers did not expect a developer to try.  I would use try/catch style error tests/handers. If nginx is not granting permission to a resource, that sounds like a configuration is wrong or not present, but hard to say.  You can not rely on a fire alarm to put out the fire, nor does having one preclude being careful with naked flames.  Error messages can be helpful but does provide a developer an infallible safety net.   I see below you found it was a bug in another plugin.  Wordpress plugins are too global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a plugin "Wordpress CSV Importer".  I do not know why but removing it made debugging work again.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress disables error reporting by default. You can enable wordpress debug mode by setting to true the `WP_DEBUG` constant in wp-config.php.

Here you can find more detailated instruction:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: As I said in my original post, debugging in wordpress is enabled